# Role based authentication/authorization security

Tags: security, authentication

I have my backend endpoint for registering and logging in the users delivered trough RestApi or GraphQL to be more specific.

I want to implement role based system for my users.

The admins and moderators can be created on the admin module for example:

```
{
  username: peter,
  passowrd: peter123,
  role: 'admin'
}
```

But the regular users that can be created on my application will send the same input but instead of the 'admin' the role `'user'` would be send.

I was thinking about this approach and was wondering if it's secure ?

Can users change the request object and change the role to admin, and then have super user access ?

Is there some best practices about this, or is this completely safe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never give the user the chance to say what they can do (which is, after all, what a role defines). It's like saying "Hey, I'm David, and I'm a supersaiyan" while I might just be a regular human, and then everyone blindly accept that I'm a supersaiyan.

What your authorization service should do is only allow user to say who they are (e.g. hey, I'm David) and then the authorization service should say "ok David, you are a regular user" or "ok David, you are an admin". What this means is that the authorization service must know who you are and what you are (stored, for example, in a database), and then give you permissions based on that.

I recommend you to check RBAC and ABAC libraries, they usually implement well established practices.